# Change default 'delimiters' in excel

Tags: excel

I am using Excel for Mac 2016 on macOS Sierra software. Although I have been successfully copying and pasting CSV files into excel for some time now, recently, they have begun to behave in an odd way. When I paste the data, the content of each row seems to split over many columns. Where as before one cell would have been able to contain many words, it seems now as though each cell is only able to contain one word, so it splits the content of what would normally be in one cell, over many cells, making some rows of data spread out over up to 100 columns!

I have tried Data tab>> From text>> which takes me through a Text Wizard. There I choose Delimited>> Choose Delimiters: Untick the 'Space' box ('Tab' box is still ticked)>> Column data as 'General'>> Finish. Following this process appears to import the data into its correct columns. It works. BUT, a lot of work to get there!

Question: Is there any way to change the default settings of Delimiters, so that the 'Space' delimiter does not automatically divide the data?

Comment: Welcome to [so], maybe you could ask this in [su].

Comment: @Prisoner No, this is Mac. They're different and Excel for Mac is especially  different. This should go on the site for Mac, aptly called "Ask Different"

Answer (score 19):

I found an answer! It has to do with the "Text to Columns" function:

The way fix this behavior is:

1. Select a non-empty cell
2. Do **Data -> Text to Columns**
3. Make sure to choose **Delimited**
4. Click **Next** >
5. Enable the **Tab** delimiter, disable all the others
6. Clear **Treat consecutive delimiters as one**
7. Click **Cancel**
8. Now try pasting your data again

Comment: To fix an entire file, select the first column then go to step 2

Answer (score 3):

**Choose delimiter directly in CSV file to open in Excel**

For Excel to be able to read a CSV file with a field separator used in a given CSV file, you can specify the separator directly in that file. For this, open your file in any text editor, say Notepad, and type the below string before any other data:

1. To separate values with comma: sep=,
2. To separate values with semicolon: sep=;
3. To separate values with a pipe: sep=|

In a similar fashion, you can use any other character for the delimiter - just type the character after the equality sign.

For example, to correctly open a semicolon delimited CSV in Excel, we explicitly indicate that the field separator is a semicolon:

[image]

[reference](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/change-excel-csv-delimiter/)

Answer (score 1):

I did the opposite regarding "consecutive delimiters"!

I put a tick in the box next to "Treat consecutive delimiters as one", and THEN it worked.