# Add new column in existing csv file in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I need insert new columns into one existing CSV file updated each day and as pipeline delimited

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|Table1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|         
1|10704|    |21/07/2020 15:05:54|L    |MT  |2786|NAV  |         
2|10660|    |21/07/2020 09:27:31|L    |MT  |4088|PIS  |     
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
|Table2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS         |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|           
1|10710|    |21/07/2020 19:34:00|21/07/2020 20:19:09|00:45:09| -              |L    |MT  |7806|ACC  |
2|10708|    |21/07/2020 18:28:12|21/07/2020 18:28:13|00:00:01| -              |T    |MT  |2600|LIT  |       
3|10700|    |21/07/2020 14:16:37|21/07/2020 15:19:13|01:02:36|21/07/2020 17:00|L    |MT  |4435|UHI  |       
4|10698|    |21/07/2020 14:06:45|21/07/2020 14:07:22|00:00:37|-               |B    |MT  |5789|TYK  |
5|10674|    |21/07/2020 10:21:04|21/07/2020 10:44:41|00:23:37|21/07/2020 12:30|T    |MT  |6699|FGR  |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Note that the number of columns between table 1 and table 2 are different on CSV file

For table 1 the number of column is 8

For table 2 the number of column is 10

I need adding missing columns into table 1  vs table 2

1. END DATE HOUR
2. LENGHT

I have tried preprocess csv file into a proper CSV using C#, adding missing columns, but the output is

[image]

The code have adding missing columns even table 2

How to do resolve this?

[This the csv file](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/uploads/short-url/gDHMTA4cxMEGphQJMDnFBr3WuBB.csv)

My code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int posNewColumn = 5;

        string output = @"C:\Downloads\import.csv";

        string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(output);
        List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList()).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < CSV.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CSV[i].Count > posNewColumn)
            {
                CSV[i].Insert(posNewColumn, i == 0 ? "Headername" : "END DATE HOUR");
            }
            else
            {
                CSV[i].Add(i == 0 ? "Headername" : "END DATE HOUR");
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(output, CSV.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a CSV file. A CSV file is just a text file with a specific format. It doesn't have multiple tables. The image you posted isn't relevant - it looks like you double-clicked on the file and expected Excel to somehow display it as if this were an Excel sheet. Excel can't guess what the delimiter is. It will try to *import* that data using the end user's locale settings, eg `,` or `;` as the list delimiter. I doubt *any* locale uses `|`

Comment: If you want multiple sheets and tables create and read real Excel files, eg with `Epplus`. The `xlsx` format is a zip package containing XML files. Libraries like Epplus make creating xlsx files as easy as a call to `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(customers)`

Comment: It's a CSV file produced by a server and made available for my processing

Comment: It's not. You may call it that, but it's not. You may look up what `csv` is, or even the RFC that defines it, but the short version is, it's supposed to be a *simple* text file with *commas* as value delimiters. What you have is a text *report* that needs parsing to get the data back

Comment: I don't call anything... sorry

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open the file in excel. If you do that excel only recognizes commas as the delimiter by default. If you want to use the pipe character you need to import the data into excel, or use Text to Columns under Data (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555818/change-default-delimiters-in-excel)

Comment: @schwechel that's incorrect, and no conversion is needed. Excel uses the *locale settings*.  In Europe that means it will use `;` as the delimiter. You can use different settings if you try to insert the data explicitly from `Data > Get External Data> From Text`

Comment: Good catch, I forgot about other locales

Comment: I don't understand the problem. It looks like it reads the file, adds the two columns and spits it back out pipe delimited. Is the problem that excel doesn't display it nicely?

Comment: The problem is the code adding missing columns even table 2 (here are complete column) and not only in table 1 where are missing

Comment: Let me insist that this is far from a csv file, and if whomever wrote the code that produces it called it csv, then that person is evil. :P It's a text file with fixed-length columns. Actually the pipes are not necessary at all, if you replace them all with spaces you could still parse the file. Don't you need to also add `RETURNS`?
A few hints when parsing: ignore lines that start with a pipe, if you split by pipe, ignore the last item, and beware of the extra spaces at the end of each line (you should definitely trim a lot here). Finally, also note "LENGTH" is misspelled.

Comment: How do you get the data that will be added to Table 1?

Comment: Still there, @Kooper?

Comment: @Andrew Yes I am here

Comment: Great. :) So is my solution working fine for you? Does it need anything else? Is it ok to skip the RETURN column? Did you mention the typo in "LENGTH" to those who give you the file?

Comment: @Andrew thank you your suggestion working perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt, trying to make it a little more flexible and more robust, also allowing you to insert values in the data rows while keeping the alignment.

```
string inputFile = @"import.csv";
string outputFile = @"output.csv";

bool startInserting = false;
string getLine(string endDateText, string lengthText) => $"{endDateText,-19}|{lengthText,-8}|";

var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.Length; i++)
{
    var line = fileContents[i];

    if (line.Contains("Table1"))
    {
        startInserting = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (line.Contains("Table2"))
        break;

    if (line.Length == 0 || line[0] == '|')
        continue;

    if (startInserting)
    {
        int columnIndex = 33;
        if (line[0] == 'N')
        {
            string headerLine = getLine("END DATE HOUR", "LENGHT"); // I keep the typo
            fileContents[i] = line.Insert(columnIndex, headerLine);
        }
        else if (char.IsDigit(line[0]))
        {
            string dataLine = getLine("", "");
            fileContents[i] = line.Insert(columnIndex, dataLine);
        }
    }

}

File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, fileContents);
```

This is the output:

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|Table1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|         
1|10704|    |21/07/2020 15:05:54|                   |        |L    |MT  |2786|NAV  |         
2|10660|    |21/07/2020 09:27:31|                   |        |L    |MT  |4088|PIS  |     
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
|Table2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||            
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||          
N|IDI  |TEST|START DATE HOUR    |END DATE HOUR      |LENGHT  |RETURNS         |CAUSE|KIND|NUMB|NAMES|           
1|10710|    |21/07/2020 19:34:00|21/07/2020 20:19:09|00:45:09| -              |L    |MT  |7806|ACC  |
2|10708|    |21/07/2020 18:28:12|21/07/2020 18:28:13|00:00:01| -              |T    |MT  |2600|LIT  |       
3|10700|    |21/07/2020 14:16:37|21/07/2020 15:19:13|01:02:36|21/07/2020 17:00|L    |MT  |4435|UHI  |       
4|10698|    |21/07/2020 14:06:45|21/07/2020 14:07:22|00:00:37|-               |B    |MT  |5789|TYK  |
5|10674|    |21/07/2020 10:21:04|21/07/2020 10:44:41|00:23:37|21/07/2020 12:30|T    |MT  |6699|FGR  |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Note: it's using some relatively new C# features, so if you get compilation errors you will have to do some adjustments.

Also note that I'm not inserting `RETURNS`, you talk about missing columns but for some reason skip that one.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with. I split it into two files for easier debugging, but you could undo that if you want. This reads in each line, as soon as you encounter "Table2" then you break out of the loop. If the first column contains "N" then you are in the table header and you add the header, if not then add an empty field.

It is a brittle solution that relies on the format of that file not changing, but I think it will do what you want it to do.

```
int posNewColumn = 4;

string input = @"C:\Temp\SO\import.csv";
string output = @"C:\Temp\SO\out.csv";

string[] CSVDump = File.ReadAllLines(input);
List<List<string>> CSV = CSVDump.Select(x => x.Split('|').ToList()).ToList();
foreach (List<string> line in CSV)
{
    if (line[1] == "Table2")
    {
        break;
    }
    line.Insert(posNewColumn, line[0] == "N" ? "LENGHT" : string.Empty);
    line.Insert(posNewColumn, line[0] == "N" ? "END DATE HOUR" : string.Empty);
}

File.WriteAllLines(output, CSV.Select(x => string.Join("|", x)));
```

Comment: What about the data rows? And the padding? Besides, I wouldn't call `Insert` for each line, why not place those inside an `if` block instead?

Comment: This does insert two empty columns for each data row. I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say "padding". The reason I do the insert for each row is to try and keep a consistent number of columns in the file.

Comment: @schwechel thanks for this help, really appreciated

Comment: Regarding the padding, I mean that the output file is no longer nicely readable as all columns are no longer aligned. Furthermore, you are adding pipes to the header lines. You should include trailing spaces in the column titles, and the corresponding spaces (or values if any) in the data rows.